# Trouble understanding C# lambda expression

Tags: c#, lambda

I have been studying java for quite a while now but have just started learning C#. I'm really struggling to understand how the program below produces the answer 101. If anyone could walk me through it that would be great.

```
void Main() {
 var x = F(n => n+1, n => n*n)(10);
 Console.WriteLine("{0}", x);
}

public Func<int,int> F (Func<int,int>p, Func<int,int>q) {
 return x => p(q(x));
}
```

Comment: specifically, what are you having a problem with?

Comment: Pretty much everything...I can't see how the program gets the answer 101

Comment: There are two functions being passed to `F` - `p` & `q`. `q` is applied first to `x` and `p` is applied to the result of that. Since `x == 10` then you have `10 * 10` and then `100 + 1`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, the type `Func<T,U>` is a delegate type for a function with a single input of type `T` and an output of type `U`. So in this example, the function `F` takes two inputs: `p` is a function that takes an integer as an input and returns an integer as an output, as is `q`. The function `F` also returns a `Func<int, int>` object. The function returned by `F` is the one that first calls `q`, and then calls `p` with the output of `q` passed into `p`.

In `Main`, the function that adds one (`n => n + 1`) is passed in as the value of `p` and the square function (`n => n * n`) is passed in for `q`. This means that `F` returns a new function that takes its input, squares it (performs the operation of `q`) and then adds one (performs the operation of `p`).

Finally, `10` is supplied as an argument to this function, so the result is `10*10 + 1 = 101`.